# Evaluate: $I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan\left ( \alpha (x-\operatorname{arsinh} x) \right ) }{x\sqrt{1+x^2} }\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I am interested this type integrals. Let
$$
I(\alpha):=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan\left ( \alpha 
(x-\operatorname{arsinh} x) \right ) }{x\sqrt{1+x^2} }\text{d}x.
$$
For example, some simple calculations showed that
$$
I\left ( \frac{1}{\pi}  \right )=-\pi\ln\left ( \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{2}  \right ).
$$
**My Question is**: 
Are there any extended results about $I(\alpha)$? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:- $$\frac{d}{dx}arsinh(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Comment: This just seems to be a variant of [Integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\operatorname{arccot}\left(1+\frac{2\pi}{\operatorname{arcoth}x-\operatorname{arccsc}x}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/521993/471884). Please include your attempts (for instance, how you proved the result for $I(1/\pi)$).

Comment: Well after differentiation under integral sign, I obtained that if we know the value of $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(\alpha)^{2}(sinh(u)-u)^{2}}du$$ then we can easily evaluate the Integral.

Comment: @RAHUL You probably didn't do the differentiation correctly. Check it out.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, I didn't differentiate $I(\alpha)$ directly. I substituted $x=sinh(u)$ then performed the differentiation, it will lead to same formula that I mentioned.

Comment: @RAHUL Following your steps, I got $$I'(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh u-u}{\sinh u(1+\alpha^2(\sinh u-u)^2)}\, du$$

Comment: Yes, now split $\frac{\sinh u-u}{\sinh u(1+a^2(\sinh u-u)^2)}$ and notice that $sinh(u)$ terms cancel each other, we get two Integrals. If we know the value of atleast one then we can calculate the entire value by adding and subtracting it once again.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, I already posted this question yesterday on math overflow. The answers were that, the integral doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: @RAHUL Thanks for the info. Can you please give me the link of the post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131057/discussion-between-rahul-and-laxmi-narayan-bhandari).

Answer (score 0):

I am very close to solution, but not exactly. Let,
$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(\alpha(xt-\operatorname{arsinh} x))}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Do substitution,
$$u=\operatorname{arsinh}x\implies du=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(\alpha(t\sinh u-u))}{\sinh u}du$$
Now differentiate on both sides wrt $t$
$$I'(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{csch}u}{1+(\alpha)^{2}(t\sinh u-u)^{2}}\alpha \sinh u du$$
Notice that $\sinh u$ and $\operatorname{csch} u$ cancels off each other.
$$I'(t)=\alpha \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(\alpha)^{2}(t\sinh u-u)^{2}}du$$
Now I am stuck here. The integral is simplified to some extent. But I have no clue what to do next. I tried to make use of $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k\ge 0}x^{k}, |x|<1$.
But using that brings us to something inside the integral which doesn't have an anti-derivative. And also if we can do the substitution $q=t\sinh u-u$ then I think something can be done. But, it's derivative is $t\cosh u-1$ which I am unable to express in terms of $q$.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc, do you know how to proceed?

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, let me know your opinion on my answer. I meant by how to continue solving it.