# Integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-x} \frac{(\sin x)^{1/2}}{(\sin x)^{1/2} + (\cos x)^{1/2}}\textrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-x} \frac{(\sin x)^{1/2}}{(\sin x)^{1/2} + (\cos x)^{1/2}}\textrm dx$$

I can't seem to solve this integral, I have tried integration by parts as well as some substitutions. Please help, a hint would be better appreciated.
P.S. This is my first time posting question in coded format, sorry if it's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a simple answer?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I am

Comment: And do you happen to know what that simple answer is?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, 0.339727. I found this using wolfram alpha. This question was given to a friend of mine by his teacher, who too has been unable to solve this.

Comment: @Confused_nerd, I wonder how did you conclude that integral has a simple answer. Note that merely convergence doesn't mean that answer is simple.

Comment: By that argument, whenever an integral converges to *something*, it is simple.

Comment: @RAHUL I am not sure what you mean "simple", isn't an answer to a finite integral a simple real number?? Sorry, but if there are "complex" answers, then I am not aware of them.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, Sir I believe that merely convergence doesn't suffice that integral is simple(My argument is that, it depends on anti-derivative of the integral). Sir, for instance have a look at this,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4293416/evaluate-i-alpha-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-left-alpha-x-operatorn. It converges but not simple

Comment: @Confused_nerd, Honestly speaking I don't know how answer looks like and how complicated it is. But it just seems to me that it's difficult. That's it.

Comment: This seems hopeless and mostly a waste of time, not sure why would a teacher give this. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872238/515527) (unanswered for quite a few years).

Comment: @Zacky This is literally the same question. Just one substitution away.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yes, but it can't be marked as a duplicate since that has no answers.

Comment: @Zacky That's the main problem. Is there any way to merge two different posts?

Comment: @Zacky Thanks for the link to other question, I will not waster any more time on this.

Comment: @Confused_nerd definitely the right choice.

Comment: Has anyone tried this with a square contour?