# Trigonometric Integral : $\int\frac{1}{\sin x+ 3\cos x}dx$

Tags: integration

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: How to integrate this integral
$$\int\frac{1}{\sin x+ 3\cos x}dx$$

Comment: Perhaps you could use a more informative title?

Comment: Perhaps by using the [tangent half-angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) ?

Comment: @Lucian that's the answer to every question :)

Comment: @IgorRivin: Even to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464769/how-to-prove-int-01-tan-1-left-frac-tanh-1x-tan-1x-pi-tanh-1) one ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian especially this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int \frac 1 {\sin x +3\cos x}\ dx &= \int \frac 1 {2\sin \frac x 2\cos \frac x 2 +3\cos^2 \frac x 2 - 3 \sin^2 \frac x 2}\ dx \\
&= \int \frac 1 {\cos^2 \frac x 2} \cdot \frac 1 {3 + 2\tan \frac x 2 - 3 \tan^2 \frac x 2}\ dx
\end{align*}

Switching $y=\tan \frac x 2 \implies\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac 1 2 \frac 1 {\cos^2 \frac x 2}$

\begin{align*}
\int \frac 1 {\sin x +3\cos x}\ dx 
&= \int \frac 1 {3 + 2y - 3 y^2}2\ dy \\
&= 6\int \frac 1 {(3y-1-\sqrt{10})(3y-1+\sqrt{10})} \ dy \\
&= \frac 3 {\sqrt{10}}\int \frac 1 {3y-1-\sqrt{10}} - \frac 1 {3y-1+\sqrt{10}} \ dy \\
\end{align*}

I'll leave the rest.

Answer (score 4):

$$1\cdot \sin x +3 \cdot \cos x=\sqrt{10} \cdot \sin (x+a)$$
where $a=\tan ^{-1}(3)$

So, now can you just apply the known integral of $\csc(x+a) $?