# Integrating $\int\frac{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\sin x}\,\text{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The integral is $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\sin x}\,\text{d}x$$ I have tried solving this by taking the sine inside the radical as follows: $$\int\sqrt\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin^2 x}\,\text{d}x$$$$\int\sqrt\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\sin^2 x}\,\text{d}x$$$$\int\sqrt{\cot^2x-1}\,\text{d}x$$ I don't know how to proceed from here, or whether this is even right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) ?

Comment: This leads to the same answer as that by substituting $\cos x = t$, right? Or that's what I got.

Comment: See also: [Evaluation of $\int\frac{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\sin x}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876175)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can continue like this:
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}\,dx&=\int\frac{\cot^2(x)-1}{\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}}\,dx\\
&=\int\frac{\csc^2(x)-2}{\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}}\,dx\\
&=\int\frac{\csc^2(x)}{\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}}\,dx-2\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}}\,dx\\
\end{align*}
The first integral can be solved with substitution $u=\cot(x)$ and the second one with substitution $\cot(x)=\cosh(t)$ will be converted to the following one:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}}\,dx&=-\int\frac{dt}{1+\cosh^2(t)}\\
&=-\int\frac{2}{2+e^t+e^{-t}}\,dt\\
&=-\int\frac{2e^t}{e^{2t}+2e^t+1}\,dt\\
&=-\int\frac{2e^t}{(e^t+1)^2}\,dt\\
&=\frac{2}{e^t+1}
\end{align*}
Can you continue?( I hope you can)

Comment: Perhaps you might want to tackle [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464769/how-to-prove-int-01-tan-1-left-frac-tanh-1x-tan-1x-pi-tanh-1) integral as well ?

Comment: Yes I can :) Thank you :)

Comment: Nice Solution Farshad Nahangi....

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you express everything in terms of $\cos(x)$ and later make a change of variables such that $y = \cos(x)$. Remember that $\frac{dx}{\sin(x)}$ is also $\frac{-d(\cos(x)) }{1-\cos^2(x)}$. Does this help and can you continue from here ?

Comment: @freak_warrior. Thanks for editing. I am almost blind and, beside plain ASCII, everything is difficult to me. Cheers.

Comment: haha no problem

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : Your answer is right as well :) I just can accept only one answer. But I like your method :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t= \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}$ to have $$dt= \frac{\sin x}{ {\cos^{3/2}2x}}dx,\>\>\>\>\>
(t^2-1)(2t^2-1)=\frac{\sin^2t}{\cos^2 2x}$$
and
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\sin x}\ dx\\
=&\int \frac{\cos^2 2x}{\sin^2x }\cdot\frac{\sin x}{{\cos^{3/2}2x}} dx
= \int\frac1{(t^2-1)(2t^2-1)}dt\\
=&\int \left(\frac1{t^2-1}-\frac{2}{2t^2-1} \right) dt
=-\coth^{-1}t+\sqrt2 \coth^{-1}\sqrt2t\\
=& - \coth^{-1} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{\cos 2x}} +\sqrt2 \coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2 \cos x}{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}
\end{align}
Similarly
\begin{align}
&\int\frac{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\cos x}\ dx
=\cot^{-1} \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos 2x}} -\sqrt2 \cot^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2 \sin x}{\sqrt{\cos 2x}}
\end{align}